# How to compute the Euclidean distance between two complex matrix by vectorization?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, euclidean-distance

`X=[x_1,x_2,...,x_N]` is a `[S,N]` complex matrix.
For example, `S=3` and `x_1=[1+2j,2+3j,3+4j]'`.

`D` is the distance matrix of `X`, which means `D(i,j)` is the Euclidean distance between `x_i` and `x_j`.

my code:

```
D = zeros(N, N);
for i = 1:N
    for j = i:N 
        D(i, j) = norm(X(:, i) - X(:, j));
    end
end
D = D + D.';
```

How to simplify it by vectorization?

I try using two loops but it costs time when N is large.
And the complex matrix can not be computed by `pdist`.

Comment: D is initialized to:  D=zeros(N,N);

Comment: The inner loop should be `for j = i+1:N`, because there is no point in computing the diagonal, which should be zero.

Comment: You say X is a matrix, but the example is a 1D matrix (i.e. a vector), is that always the case or do you need a solution which works for 2D matrices? How big is N? That might matter as for large N a loop could be as quick as creating large intermediate matrices required to vectorise

Comment: @Wolfie：
x_1 is the first vector of X and X is one 2D matrix. N=4000 in my project, and this double loops cost about 6 s to finish, but this operation is in another for-loop, thus costs much time totally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To vectorize this code, you need to build an intermediate 3D matrix:

```matlab
D = vecnorm(reshape(X, S, 1, N) - X);
D = reshape(D, N, N);  % or just squeeze(D)
```

This takes up lots of space, but since `S=3`, the additional space is not prohibiting and doesn't seem to slow down the computation. For much larger `S`, vectorized code would use the cache less efficiently because of the larger memory footprint.

Note that loops used to be slow a long time ago, but this is no longer the case. In very old MATLAB versions, and in Octave, it is always beneficial to avoid loops, but in modern MATLAB versions it is not. One needs to time the code to know for sure what is fastest.

---

To speed up OP's code without removing loops, we can do the following:

```matlab
D = zeros(N, N);
for i = 1:N
    for j = i+1:N  % Skip the diagonal!
        D(j, i) = vecnorm(X(:, i) - X(:, j));
    end
end
D = D + D.';
```

I made three changes:

1. When looping over a 2D matrix, the inner loop should always be the first index. This makes best use of the cache. Over `X` you loop correctly (indexing columns), but over `D` the order was reversed.
2. Using `vecnorm` instead of `norm`. This is a relatively new function, and is faster because it's simpler (it does just one thing).
3. Skipping the diagonal, which we know will be all zeros.

Answer (score 0):

The distance matrix of the complex matrix can be computed as the sum of the distance matrices of the real and the imaginary parts:

```
D = squareform(sqrt(pdist(real(X).').^ 2 + pdist(imag(X).').^ 2));
```